# Interaction between widget and plot with Bokeh Server

Tags: python, bokeh

I discover Bokeh library.
I try to use Jupyter notebook to publish some app with interaction into Bokeh server.

So I:

- Launch Bokeh server
- Launch app with Jupyter notebook
- Try to interact with app into browser

But interaction doesn't work.
Code I launch from Jupyter notebook (A simple update of my title plot)

```
from bokeh.plotting       import figure, output_server, show
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput
from bokeh.io             import curdoc

# Create output test_num1
output_server("test_num1")

# Create a figure and add a line
plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title="Test")
plot.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], name='ex_line')

# Create TextInput and add 
text_input = TextInput(value="default", title="Label:")

def update_title(attrname, old, new):
    plot.title = text_input.value

text_input.on_change('value', update_title)

# Create a document with the plot and text_input
curdoc().add(plot,text_input)

# Show the result
show(curdoc)
```

I don't know if my code is wrong or if I miss something about how this thing work.

Comment: If I remember correctly bokeh didnt work with jupyter notebooks before version 0.12.x.

Comment: That's not the case, Bokeh has worked in the notebooks since roughly version 0.4, with some hiccups along the way as both Bokeh and the notebook both developed heavily. The issue here is that `on_change` callbacks require a Bokeh server (which can be embedded in a notebook)